# Swift send parameters in Alamofire

Tags: php, json, swift, alamofire

I want to send two values in the request:

1) operation string

2) user object

I am getting message `Operation is not set` even though I included in parameters `"operation": "register"`

I am new to Alamofire. Can anyone explain to me:

1) how to send values in the request?

2) how to send the user object?

3) how to deal with both results `.Success` and `.Failure`

Swift Code:

```
let urlString = URLFactory()
let url = URL(string: urlString.getAppURL())!
print("Log url: \(url)")

let user = User()
user.setEmail(email: email)

let parameters: Parameters = ["operation": "register", "user": user]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
    print("Log \(response)")
    print("Log response.request: \(response.request)")
    print("Log response.error: \(response.error)")
    print("Log response.data: \(response.data)")
    print("Log response.result: \(response.result)")
}
```

Swift Output:

```
Log url: http://192.168.0.101/GeolocationNews/NewsDataCrawler/app.php
Log SUCCESS: {
    message = "Invalid Parameters";
    result = failure;
}
Log response.request: Optional(http://192.168.0.101/GeolocationNews/NewsDataCrawler/app.php)
Log response.error: nil
Log response.data: Optional(51 bytes)
Log response.result: SUCCESS
```

PHP Code:

```
$login = new Login();
$fun = new FunctionsValidation();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    if(isset($data->operation)) {
        $operation = $data->operation;
        if(!empty($operation)) {
            if($operation == 'register') {
                echo $login->register($data);
            }
        } else { // if operation is empty
            $response["result"] = "failure";
            $response["message"] = "Operation is empty";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else { // if operation is not set
        $response["result"] = "failure";
        $response["message"] = "Operation is not set";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have tested the API by Postman sending:

```
{
    "operation": "register",
    "user":
    {
        "email": "email value"
    }
}
```

It gives me: `{"result":"failure","message":"Invalid Email"}` so the API is working good!

I have tried sending Alamofire request with just operation in the parameters and it works. So it seems like the problem is in converting the user object to dictionary. Can anyone give me an example of how to do that?

User object:

```
class User: NSObject {

    private var name: String,
                email: String,
                password: String,
                oldPassword: String,
                newPassword: String,
                code: String
    private var id: Int

    override init() {
        self.name = ""
        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.oldPassword = ""
        self.newPassword = ""
        self.code = ""
        self.id = 0
    }
    // set and get methods ...
}
```

Comment: How are you parsing "User". It looks like you are trying to send User as a Swift object. Can you first test out your api through REST client for e.g. Postman

Comment: @RikeshSubedi the API is returning the respond before checking the user. It first check the operation then return `"Operation is not set"` without reading the user. So user is not the issue here - at least for now

Comment: @JumanaAlhaddad 
1. I think you have problem with your api - please test your api with postman with body `{"operation": "register"}`
2. You need convert `User` object to dictionary

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski I have tested the API and it's working good! see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with converting the user object to a dictionary. Instead of using an object, I just set the user as a dictionary.

```
let userDictionary: Dictionary = ["email": email, "password": password]
let parameters: Parameters = ["operation": operation, "user": userDictionary]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with encoding. As per your PHP code it accepts `application/json` as a content type and this should be sent through Almofire with JSON encoding.

Try this instead:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { response in
        print("Log \(response)")
        print("Log response.request: \(response.request)")
        print("Log response.error: \(response.error)")
        print("Log response.data: \(response.data)")
        print("Log response.result: \(response.result)")
    }
```

**Reference:** 
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#parameter-encoding

Comment: thank you! do you know an example of how to convert user object to dictionary?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski I have added my user model in the post update

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan I have added `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` but still not working. It seems like the issue is in converting the user object to dictionary before passing it. I have SwiftyJSON in my project but it just shows me how to convert from JSON to dictionary not the other way.

Comment: @JumanaAlhaddad I saw yours postman and that `let parameters: Parameters = ["operation": "register", "user": ["email": user.email]]` should be enough